# Bootstrap 4 alignment in IE 11

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm converting one of my websites from AngularJs / Bootstrap 3 to Angular 6 / Bootstrap.

In Chrome and firefox, and edige, my modal looks like this:

[image]

However, in IE11

[image]

The code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="modal-header">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (keydown.enter)="onKeydown($event)">
          <div class="row form-group">
              <div class="col-12">
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" formControlName="userName" required autofocus />
                  <p *ngIf="!isValidUserName" class="help-block alert-danger">Invalid Username</p>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-12">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password" required />
                <p *ngIf="!isValidPassword" class="help-block alert-danger">Invalid Password</p>
            </div>
          </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <button class="btn loginBtn" (click)="login(userName.value, password.value)">
                        Login
                    </button>
                    <p *ngIf="loginError" class="help-block alert-danger">{{ loginError }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row form-group">
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <label class="forgotPasswordLink" (click)="openForgotPasswordModal()">
                        Forgot password?
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row form-group">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                    <button type="button" (click)="googleLogin()" class="btn btnGoogle googleIcon">
                        <span class="button-text">Login with Google</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                    <button type="button" (click)="linkedInLogin()" class="btn btnLinkedIn linkedinIcon">
                        <span class="button-text">Login with LinkedIn</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row form-group">
                <div class="col-12 text-center">
                    Don't have an account? <a (click)="signUp()">Sign up</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I took a look on github, but none of those solutions seem to work to the best of my knowledge, is there a way to fix this inconsistency at a site level?

Comment: check bootstrap 4 API, because most of the classes name got changed, also ng-bootstrap uses bootstrap 4.

Comment: @Pankaj I did, col-xs-12  becomes col-12, etc... and I had to add the grid div, so I got it working in all the browsers, but IE11, my question centers more around what else I need to do to get it working in IE11.

Comment: After spending some more time on it, my best solution is to get rid of the row / col completely and just use divs since it's just a modal, however I'd still like a bs4 solution as other parts of the new site are being affected, I tried flex: 1 0 auto and a few other solutions with no luck, so I'm adding a bounty to help draw attention.

Comment: Have you try to modify the css using -ms prefix? Equivalent of webkit of chrome but for IE11 and above

Comment: Can you please post some working link where we can see it ?

Comment: @Nandita it's a commercial site, so... not easily.  However, all I'm really looking for  is an example of a ngx-bootstrap modal (the ngx part probably doesn't matter) that works in IE11 and uses bs4, or flexbox classes with similar buttons on the bottom.

Comment: can you please post your code here? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slvxld

Comment: I've created stackblitz with the code you've posted - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h8b2b8 please add the missing code, once we'll reproduce the problem we could help you

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix a very similar issue by adding

```
flex: 1 0 auto;
```

on `span` with `col-12` that contained the message/text of the modal.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `container` can you try using `container-fluid`

It looks like it may have do to some `width:auto` styling?
[Bootstrap 4 IE 11 does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46502273/bootstrap-4-ie-11-does-not-work)

If you're looking at the site side-by-side on IE and Chrome you can use the F12 dev tools to look at the elements and styles, you just have to find the element/styling that is rendering differently.

Comment: if you can create a StackBlitz or something like that we can take a look at it online

Answer (score -1):

```
.container,.modal-header,.modal-body,modal-footer, input{
width: 100% !important;
}


div{
display:block;
float:left;
}
```

Comment: While this may provide a solution for the question, you should describe in more detail why.